# EditText focus jumps to other EditText when tapping

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 2 `EditTexts` one next to each other.
when tapping the right one the focus jumps to the left one.

This happens only on Samsung S9.
Tested on pixel, S7 and some Samsung tablet

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:baselineAligned="false">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minWidth="40dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/a1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="60dp"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/questionFreeTextInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/a2"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestions why does this happen?

Comment: Are you using them in linear layout ? If you are using weights then you also need to show the code of parent view which carry these two textinputlayouts.

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan edited my question

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with assigning weights and min widths.

Comment: @ilan keep a background to both the text View and check if the are overlapping each other in s9 device if they are overlapping then you have to set them up relative to each other or with constraint's

Comment: there are not overlapping.
the focus starts at the correct edittext but after a few milliseconds jumps to the wrong one